# How to loop through a SSIS dataset concatenating all column 2 items where column 1/3/4 is identical

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, ssis, concatenation

In SSIS I am pulling a set of data where column 1 is account numbers and duplicates exist, column 2 is a unique code per account.  This data is going into a SQL Server table.

i would like to combine rows so that each unique account (column 1) has its own line with all SVC. This will likely have to go in a script task, VB or C# would work, however I am slightly more comfortable with VB (VBA moreso).  I understand it may require a recordset as well.

```
    ORIGINAL STYLE
    account             svc     rem_date    remove_indicator
    8888777766665555    CE1     9/25/2016   6
    8888777766665555    FB6     9/25/2016   6
    8888555566667777    CE1     9/26/2016   6
    8888555566667777    FB6     9/26/2016   6

    NEW STYLE
    account             svc       rem_date   remove_indicator
    8888777766665555    CE1,FB6   9/25/2016  6
    8888555566667777    CE1,FB6   9/26/2016  6
```

Searches only seem to turn up concatenating all rows together regardless of columns.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why 1D is always the first element? Is there an implied ordering or would FB6@CE1,PP,1D be just as legitimate?

Comment: What if account ending in 5 had activity on 3/26 - does it roll up to a new line because you are aggregating based on account and one/both dates?

Comment: @billinkc it just happens that this sample they each had 1D.  If the DSC column has data, it should be concatenated with the same row SVC data with a  '@' in between, then all other rows just get comma separation.  Really, the codes in SVC and DSC can be anything, as long as  they are concatenated in  SVC@DSC,SVC,SVC@DSC format as needed.  if the dates are different, those related columns would be in their own respective line as well

Comment: Just as a forewarning, this likely a terrible idea for the svc column as you have now magnified the complexity of ever using the data in the column

Comment: I appreciate the warning, however the modified data would go into a new sql server table leaving the originals untouched, and the new results would then be fed into a process to make changes to these accounts and they require the  SVC@DSC,SVC,SVC@DSC type of format

Comment: Warning delivered ;) So, Would a value of SVC2@DSC2,SVC3,SVC1@DSC1 be just as valid as SVC3,SVC1@DSC1,SVC2@DSC2 as SVC1@DSC1,SVC2@DSC2,SVC3?

Comment: yes, that layout would be valid.  Obviously if DSC is empty, there should be no @DSC.

Comment: I apologize!! - i do not have the DSC or ADD_DATE columns!... i only need to concatenate the SVC items per account per REM_DATE

Comment: To echo @billinkc's warning.  How are you going to a single rem_date and remove_indicator value in each row of your output?  There may be multiple values for each of these, for each account, in multiple input rows.

Comment: @sebthu i understand your concern, but due to the sorted table i have and to keep the process simple, each account (col 1) should only end up with the one rem_date and remove_indicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!! - i can do it all in SQL using STUFF

```
    insert into table 2
    select account, 
        stuff((select ','+service_code 
            from table 1 
            where account = a.account 
            for xml path('')),1,1,'') as svcconc, 
        a.remove_date, 
        '' as service_adds
    from (select distinct account,
                remove_date 
        from table 1)a 
    group by account, remove_date
```